# pymongo - use a custom cursor class

Tags: iterator, pymongo

Is it possible in pymongo to have the `collection.find()` method return a custom cursor class that inherits from the base, but redefines how iteration occurs?

I'd like to instantiate app specific models from the mongo data within the cursor right at iteration time.  The documents have a `type` attr that will determine what kind of instance should be created.  I was thinking the `next` method could look within this data and decide which type to create and return.  Inheriting from the cursor is easy enough, but I can't figure out where to hook this into the `find()` operation?

**EDIT** Alternatively...

What I'm doing currently is to use `yield` to spit out a generator that will classify the object after the fact when the fetch is performed.

```
@classmethod
def gather(cls,place_id):
    """
    Gather instances of all the shouts for one place
    """
    shouts = cls.collection.find({'place_id':place_id})
    for s in shouts:
        yield Shout.classify(s)

@classmethod
def classify(cls,shout):
    if shout.type == 1:
        return Type1(dict(shout))
    elif shout.type == 2:
        return Type2(dict(shout))
    elif shout.type == 3:
        return Type3(dict(shout))
```

The problem is that this doesn't preserve the original approach to bracket key access that is encapsulated in the default pymongo `Cursor`.

If I were to create a wrapper class that will just accept a cursor instance and wrap its methods, which magic methods will I need to override to preserve the iteration behavior of the original cursor?  I'm thinking something like this:

```
class StuffCursor():

    cursor = False

    def __init__(self,cursor):
        self.cursor = cursor

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        #This passes off most key-based calls, like bracket-access, to the cursor
        return getattr(self.cursor,attr)
```

This is just what I could think of, but anything that would stack some additional processing on top of an iterator, and then return the modified iterator, would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but this may prove to be of good use to anyone googling.  Here's what I ended up going with:

```
class ShoutCursor():
    """
    Custom cursor class that will instantiate shout models
    at query time.
    """

    cursor = False

    def __init__(self,cursor):
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.cursor.sort('created',DESCENDING)

    def __iter__(self):
        for ent in self.cursor:
            yield Shout.classify(ent)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.cursor.count()

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        try:
            ents = itertools.islice(self.cursor,index,index+1)
            return [Shout.classify(ent) for ent in ents][0]
        except TypeError:
            return list(Shout.classify(ent) for ent in itertools.islice(self.cursor,index.start,index.stop,index.step))

    def sort(*args,**kwargs):
        self.cursor.sort(*args,**kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.cursor,attr)
```

The `__iter__` and `__getiem__` methods are where the modified, instantiated models are loaded up into generators are returned.  The other methods preserve native cursor action.  Passing a cursor into `__init__` sets up the functionality, so special, per iteration logic can be performed as the objects are fetched from mongo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if "monkey patching" could be used to achieve this, but I ended up doing it as shown below. This allows me to add/override functions on the `Cursor` class.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.collection import Collection
from pymongo.cursor import Cursor
from pymongo.database import Database

class CustomCursor(Cursor):
    # Customize Cursor here, either by overriding or extending with more methods


class CustomCollection(Collection):
    def __init__(self, database: Database, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(database, name)

    # find_one seems to use find, but you may need to override in more places.
    def find(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return CustomCursor(self, *args, **kwargs)


class CustomDatabase(Database):
    def __init__(self, client: MongoClient, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(client, name)

    def __getitem__(self, name: str) -> CustomCollection:
        return CustomCollection(self, name)

# usage:
client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)
database = CustomDatabase(client, 'mydb')
```

I defined a `Serializable` base class, with a `from_dict` and `to_dict` method. This allowed me to define a `to_list()` on the `CustomCursor` so that I could query and get class-instances back:

```
result: List[School] = database.schools.find().to_list(School)
```